# Edit SVG font using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, typography

I opened an SVG font in Inkscape but I cant see any character editor. Is anyone able to explain how to open/modify a character path ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple SVG font editor, in the menu: Text > SVG font editor.

There is a [good description](http://cleversomeday.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/inkscape-dings/) and even [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX-e6sijGE).

> Buried in Inkscape .47 is the ability to make your own SVG fonts. This
>   isn’t all that exciting because even InkScape can’t use SVG fonts.
>   However, pair this with a free font conversion tool and you now have a
>   way to create your own TrueType fonts for free!

You have two other options:

- Create your own font using a font editing tool
- Mark the characters, then use InkScape Path>Object to Path

The last option is easy, but could be tedious depending on the amount of text you want to tweak. Of cause you now have paths, not text, so correcting spelling errors would be a pain!

Comment: Then why Inkscape offers a "SVG font editor" if it is not possible to edit a font ?

Comment: I updated answer.

Comment: This is great for creating new fonts, but how do you edit and existing one?

Comment: You will need a font editing tool. Google it. It is will no always be legal to use it depending on the font license.